# How can I get the object attributes in android compose?

Tags: android, attributes, android-jetpack-compose

I'm migrating an app from standard Android Views to the new Compose API, and I need to access some object attributes. With Views, I used to get them easily through bindings:

```
val pivotX = binding.imageBottle.pivotX
val pivotY = binding.imageBottle.pivotY
val xPostion = binding.imageBottle.x
val yPostion = binding.imageBottle.y
```

But with compose, I don't know how to access them. I have been able to get the size using an ugly way like:

```
val imageDraw: Painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_champers)
Image(modifier = Modifier
    .rotate(rotation)
    .onSizeChanged { 
        val width = it.width.toFloat()
        val height = it.height.toFloat() },
    painter = imageDraw,
    contentDescription = "Image"
)
```

Using Android Compose, what is the right way to get the attributes of the objects? I'm mainly interested on the position, size and PivotX/PivotY.

Just as a side note, with the Layout Inspector I can see the attributes, but I need to access to them from the code.

Comment: This is the right way to get the view size, but in compose you almost never need it. You need to change your way of thinking to build a compose layout, I suggest you start with [tutorials](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial).

Comment: What is the final goal ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, I want to rotate an image with an animation. I want the initial velocity proportional to the angle of the this two vectors: (Image pivot point -> point detected with ACTION_DOWN) and this second vector (Image pivot point -> point detected with ACTION_UP). I have almost everything migrated, but I have the "Pivot" point of the image hardcoded, because I have'nt found a way to get it. Thanks! (You can find the original app here: https://github.com/xaviarmengol/CrazyBottle2)